# Is there any available object detecting/recognition C# library?

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm working on a project that need to regconize object in the real world ( like fruits, chairs, notebook, table, speaker... blah blah )

The first thing i would like to ask is that "Is it possible?", i'm currently a third-years student at University of Information technology

And the second is that "Is there any available C# library that help me to do this?"

Is there any solution for this?
I will be very grateful if there is anyone that can answer my questions!

Comment: Check out OpenCV. Idk if there's C# bindings.

Comment: Do you mean that you will pass an object, and you have to determine the type of object from the list of real world objects you already have with you?

Comment: I will pass an image, then the library would help me to determine what objects is in the image

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is a very difficult task. Keep in mind that designing a perfect system that **always** detects the object and produces no errors (false alarms) is currently impossible.

You can start by using OpenCV's latent SVM detector:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

However, training new models is problematic. You can also use OpenCV HOG descriptor and detector: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html

or cascade classifier: 
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html

You should limit yourself to a predefined set object and train a detector for each object class. If you can limit yourself to the set of classes that OpenCV's latent svm currently supports, it actually won't be that hard of a task. But keep in mind that there always will be missed detections and false alarms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Alturos.Yolo](https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.Yolo) it is a c# wrapper for [yolo (darknet)](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/). Dependent on the pre-trained model you can detect a lot of different objects ([list of trained objects of Yolo9000](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/master/build/darknet/x64/data/9k.names)). You can also train custom objects if you need more variety.

Nuget package

```
PM> install-package Alturos.Yolo
```

Example

```
var configurationDetector = new ConfigurationDetector();
var config = configurationDetector.Detect();
//using (var yoloWrapper = new YoloWrapper("yolov2-tiny-voc.cfg", "yolov2-tiny-voc.weights", "voc.names"))
using (var yoloWrapper = new YoloWrapper(config))
{
    var items = yoloWrapper.Detect(@"image.jpg");
    //items[0].Type -> "Person, Car, ..."
    //items[0].Confidence -> 0.0 (low) -> 1.0 (high)
    //items[0].X -> bounding box
    //items[0].Y -> bounding box
    //items[0].Width -> bounding box
    //items[0].Height -> bounding box
}
```